# Special Soundness $\Sigma$-Protocols

Tags: soundness, sigma-protocol

About the characterizations of Special Soundness, from [Staking Sigmas](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/422) we have that:

''A $\Sigma$-protocol $\Pi=(A,Z,\phi)$ is said to have ${\it special\ soundness}$ if there exists a PPT extractor $\mathcal{E}$, such that given any two transcripts $(x,a,c,z)$ and $(x,a,c',z')$, where $c\ne c'$ and $\phi(x,a,c,z)=\phi(x,a,c',z')=1$, it holds that
\begin{align*}
    \Pr[\mathcal{R}(x,w)=1|w\leftarrow\mathcal{E}(1^\lambda,x,a,c,z,c',z')]=1,
\end{align*}''

which is essentially the same stated in [On $\Sigma$-protocols](https://cs.au.dk/%7Eivan/Sigma.pdf) with different notation:

''From any $x$ and any pair of accepting conversations on input $x$, $(a, e, z)$, $(a,e',z')$ where $e\ne e'$, one can efficiently compute $w$ such that $(x,w)\in R$. This is sometimes called the ${\it special\ soundness}$ property.''

So my question is, why is this a desirable property? shouldn't we want to avoid this? i.e. shouldn't it be infeasible for an extractor to retrieve the witness even if it produces two accepting transcripts?

Answer (score 1):

I'll focus on the definition/notation of Damgard since it's the one I am more familiar with. An important element of the definition is that both transcripts need to be with respect to the *same* first message (the commitment) $a$, but with different challenges. So as long as this first message is probabilistic, one is unlikely to receive two transcripts with the same $a$ when interacting with an honest prover.

This was why the definition is not problematic. The reasons why this is a desirable property are the following.

First, it implies regular soundness: if $x\notin L$, then for any commitment $a$, being able to respond to two different challenges $e\neq e'$ means being able to reconstruct a witness for $x$. Since $x\notin L$, there is no such witness, so this means there is a single challenge that will be accepted and the probability of accepting a false statement is $\frac 1M$ where $M$ is the size of the challenge space. I've also seen this unique challenge property being useful when proving other properties of a scheme.

Secondly, special soundness also implies knowledge soundness, i.e. a special sound proof is a proof of knowledge. To show this, one has to construct an extractor that interacts with a prover and produces a valid witness. If the proof is special sound, then the extractor can proceed as follows: run the prover until it outputs the first message $a$, send it a challenge $e$ and get a response $z$, now rewind the prover to its state before receiving the challenge, send it a different challenge $e'$ and get a different response $z'$. If both transcripts are accepting, then by the special soundness property it is possible to recover a witness for $x$ in polynomial time.